# Scaling an iframe with webkitTransform in Safari creates white border

Tags: css, iframe, html, safari

I have a simple html page in an iframe that I am trying to scale with an html5 input range slider. it creates a white border inside the iframe, what looks to be a doubling side effect.

It works perfect in chrome(6.0.472.59 mac), but not in safari (5.0.1 mac).

here is a link to live demo - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1031653/safari-bug.html

Any sort of suggestion on why this may be happening? hardcore hacks are fine if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a Safari bug. I would recommend reporting it at https://bugs.webkit.org/

Comment: Thanks! I will clean it up a bit and submit it.

Comment: @TomSwift did you ever submit this bug? I noticed that this is now only happening on Safari for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this bug in Chrome as well (version 11.x.x)

One solution is to go into the IFRAME's document (assuming you have access) and set the size there. Something like this:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('body').css('-webkit-transform', 'scale(0.5)');
```